# snakemake wildcard scoping between rules

Tags: snakemake

I've read the [docs on rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html), the [FAQ](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#project-info-faq), and [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snakemake/wVlJW9X-9EU), but I still can't tell: if a wildcard `foo` is defined in rule `bar`, can its values be accessed in rule `baz`?

Comment: It is possible to pass values between rules using [this trick](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-want-to-pass-variables-between-rules-is-that-possible), but the docs there imply that wildcards don't pass values between rules.

Comment: This answer is on a very similar topic and it says that wildcards do not take the same values from one rule to the next. https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/11137/1708

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, the answer should be "no".

By using a wildcard in the rule you just define the pattern that can be applied to many different files. For example, in this rule you define the a way to produce files whose filenames match a pattern "new_name{n}.txt", where `{n}` can be any string:

```
rule example:
    input: "old_name{n}.txt"
    output: "new_name{n}.txt"
    shell: "cp input output"
```

For sure this rule will be regarded only if the file "old_name{n}.txt" exists with the same string `{n}` used.

Returning back to your question: how could you access the value if this is just a pattern that may be applied to different values?

Another possible interpretation of your question is that you need to know all the values (all the inputs) the rule `bar` was applied to. In this case you probably need to employ `checkpoint`: this is the way to delay the pattern application until the part of pipeline finishes. But even in this case you wouldn't be accessing "the values of wildcard" explicitly.

Comment: *how could you access the value if this is just a pattern that may be applied to different values?* I was imagining something like this: when a value matches {foo} in `rule bar`, it then also appears as that value in `baz`. (I'm glad this doesn't happen, but from the docs, I couldn't tell.)

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but do you have an example or any documentation to support it?

Comment: @eric_kernfeld. The wildcards in different rules are independent from each other. The rest of your question is open-ended. Please describe a concrete problem you are trying to solve, and I'll try to find the docs for you.

Comment: I am just looking for the reasoning behind what you have said, in particular your first sentence: *If I understood your question correctly, the answer should be "no".* For example, did you find some documentation that describes wild-card scoping? Did you test out an example? Or is this just common sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm answering your question and what follows may not be entirely correct... Snakemake only cares that you have one and only one path that leads to the requested files (i.e., the files defined in the first rule, usually called `all`).

If rule *bar* defines wildcards that can to lead to the final output, then yes, those wildcards are visible to the following rules.

In the script below we ask for files `A.txt` and `B.txt`. To produce A.txt we don't need any wildcard. To produce B.txt we need to pass by wildcard `{wc}` defined in rule *bar* and used in rule `B`. Note that wildcard `{sample}` doesn't appear at all outside rule `all`. Note also that rule `bar` produces two files, B.tmp and C.tmp, but rule `B` only needs `B.tmp`. (You should be able to dry-run this script with `snakemake -p -n`)

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}.txt', sample= ['A', 'B']),

rule A:
    output:
        'A.txt',
    shell:
         "touch {output}"

rule bar:
    output:
        expand('{wc}.tmp', wc= ['B', 'C'])
    shell:
        r"""
        touch {output}
        """

rule B:
    input:
        '{wc}.tmp',
    output:
        '{wc}.txt',
    shell:
        r"""
        touch {input} {output}
        """
```

Comment: I tried this out. When I replace `{wc}` in `rule B` with `{other}`, it still works. Also, the file `C.txt` is not created. So it seems that the wildcard's values from `bar` (which are `['B', 'C']`) are *not* visible in `rule B`. In other words, your example is very helpful. May I edit your answer to reflect the behavior I am observing versus the behavior my question would predict?